# I am connecting to a server using putty can i run php scripts on that? if i can how to run?

Tags: php

We connect to our server using php, I generally run shell scripts,I want to convert those scripts into php scripts.So how to know whether i can run php scripts on my server or not.So how to run these php scripts on my putty connected server?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure the PHP command line program is installed.
2. Run `php /path/to/your/script.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP CLI to run the script.

You can write like php filename.php.

If the php don't work then check for the actual path of the php.

It should be like /usr/bin/php .